# How to calculate Last column total

Tags: jquery, html

I have one HTML table. what i want is last column total.
These is the excepting result

```
    --------------------------------
   | Names     |Process_id  | total|
    --------------------------------
   |construction    1001      1001  |
   |engineering     1005      1005  |
   |total            0        2006  |
   ----------------------------------
```

[I tried some thing here](http://jsfiddle.net/ey07p6ez/)

please help me these

Thank you.

Comment: It would be better if you could post your code here instead of linking to another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
rowCount = $('#table4 tr:last').index() + 1;
var total_1 = 0;
for (i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var rows = $('#table4 tbody tr');
    var cellVal_2 = parseFloat($('#table4 tr:eq(' + i + ')').find("td:last").text().replace(',', ''));
    $('#table4 tr td:last').each(function() {
        var cellVal_1 = parseFloat($('#table4 tr:eq(' + i + ')').find("td:last").text().replace(',', ''));
        if (!isNaN(cellVal_1)) {
            total_1 = total_1 + cellVal_1;
        }
    });
}
$('#table4 tr:last td:last').html(total_1);
```

Comment: What line you modified please tell me that line.

Comment: I have pulled total_1 outside of loop to get total nothing else.

Comment: i have also modified first line and last line

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='js-total-column'>1001</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='js-total-column'>1005</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='js-total-column'></td> 
    </tr>   
  </tbody>
</table>

var totalSum = 0;
$('.js-total-column').each(function() {
    var total = $(this).html();
    totalSum += total;
});
```

Add a target class to each total cell, then iterate over them in JQuery with `.each()` performing processing one by one. Use `$(this)` to get the individual cell within the loop.

I removed the other `td`s and the `thead` from your table to focus on the stuff that matters for the answer.

You could also use html [`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes and the jquery [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method - this way you could guarantee you always get numbers. Cell contents are not necessarily stable, what happens if someone adds a `£` symbol prefix or a unit suffix to the number in HTML? Or if the designs change to require the contents to include extra HTML structure.

Comment: I don't want using class in jquery. Thank you for replay i will give you up vote. Thank for answered.

Comment: why not use class in jquery? It's a good way to do it that allows things to be more robust, for example, if the column order changes in the future.

Comment: In my table all are dynamic column. we can use the class in jquery. current requirement  not required class. Thank you

Comment: you should be able to add a class anyway as you're generating the table